# How to run java 1.5 applets inside my web browser?

Tags: 10.04, firefox, java

I need to run an applet that requires java 1.5.

It does not matter if I should uninstall java 6. 
Even doesn't matter if it applies for firefox or chrome.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to downgrade your Java. Java 6 can run Java 5 (or 1.5) applet. You just need to install the plug-in for your browser.

It depends on which flavour of Java you're using:

- if using openjdk, install **icedtea6-plugin**
- if using sun-java6, install **sun-java6-plugin**

Both packages are installable via `Synaptics` or the command line using apt-get.

If you're using the `Ubuntu Software Centre` look for respectively:

- **Icedtea Java Plugin**
- **Sun Java 6.0 Plugin**